# Increase Concurrent Remote Desktop users on a standard Azure VM

Tags: azure, remote-desktop

I have a client who has been using the default 2 allowed concurrent Remote desktop connections with a standard windows server 2022 VM in Azure. They use a VPN to keep thing secure.

Is it possible for them to fulfil their new requirement of 5 concurrent users by applying Client Access Licences or equivalent to their existing server?

Is there any way of getting round starting again from scratch with a fresh Azure RDS (remote desktop services) deployment (using Windows 2016 Datacenter)? i.e. can a remote desktop gateway in azure be setup in conjunction with the existing Windows server 2022 to upgrade the setup to something similar to an RDS?

Answer (score 1):

***I have a client who has been using the default 2 allowed concurrent Remote desktop connections with a standard windows server 2022 VM in Azure***

The 2 concurrent sessions are for administering the server, not for a desktop session being used as the user desktop. You'll need to install the RDS role and the RDS License Server role and purchase and install the appropriate number of RDS CAL's. There is no way around this. Trying to circumvent the need to purchase the appropriate number of RDS CAL's is a violation of the EULA.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-client-access-license